# gdm3 .desktop file doesn't start wine 5.0 program

Tags: wine, ubuntu-gnome

How do I fix my applicaton.desktop files to use WINE 5.0? (Ubuntu 18.04)

None of my existing application.desktop files work after upgrading to WINE 5.0; all worked with 4.0.3. As an example, executing

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/myname/.wine" /opt/wine-stable/bin/wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/myname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Steam\ Valve\ Gear/Steam\ Valve\ Gear\ Software\ Suite.lnk
```

from the command line works as expected.

The .desktop file originally had

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/myname/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/myname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Steam\\ Valve\\ Gear/Steam\\ Valve\\ Gear\\ Software\\ Suite.lnk
```

so I changed the "wine" to add the full path (/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine) but the syslog report (below) doesn't change; /opt/wine-stable/bin/wine is in my PATH, but may not be in gdm3's path
Syslog only reports:
*Feb 11 16:22:13 xxx-Gazelle wine-Programs-Steam Valve Gear-Steam Valve Gear Software Suite.desktop[24439]: env: ‘wine’: No such file or directory*
I do know I am editing the correct file because the changes occasionally cause further error reports in the syslog. The first error is always the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution was to add an /etc/profile.d/wine-env.sh with one line:
*PATH=$PATH:/opt/wine-stable/bin*

To diagnose, I created a ~/.local/share/applications/env.desktop with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=simplest possible application
Terminal=true
Name=wine env
Exec=bash --norc
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

and determined that there was no path to wine set. I looked in /etc (find-grep) for any file that set a PATH with one of the unique names reported by env in the diagnostic terminal window, read up on profile.d and decided that was as good a place as any to put it. [N.B. file name *wine-env* was chosen for easy identification; it could have been *moo* or *oink* but those were obscure. The *.sh* suffix is necessary.]